# Accessing non-public RDS from Jupyter notebook hosted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-rds

If I host a Jupyter Notebook on AWS (like [this guide shows](https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6)) will it possible for the notebook to access a non-public RDS database instance? Is there some additional setup to allow it to do so or would it just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either both the EC2 instance will have to be in the same subnet with the RDS or there should be a route table entry allowing the communication.
Also, the security group should be allowed to make egress calls to the RDS and the RDS resource policy should allow the security group.